# my code overwrites the .csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I got a critical problem. I am working on a code which should analyze data from an experiment. I got the data in a .csv file and tried import these data to work with them in MATLAB.

My problem is that my code imported the .csv data and overwrote my .csv file.
Can you help to find a way how to import the files without overwriting/erasing the original .csv file?

My code is here. Is this okay or shall I try something else?

```
fid = fopen('data.csv'); 
data = textscan(fid, '%*s %*f %f', 'delimiter', ';', 'headerlines', 5); 
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Is this the only code you use related to your `.csv` files? I don't see how this can overwrite the files. If you want to make sure, use `fid = fopen('data.csv','r');` to open as read-only

Comment: or [readtext.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946-readtext)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your posted code snippet, but the `importdata` function may be more convenient to use: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html